# create .xml file with data from bash

Tags: gnome, bash

I am trying to make a .xml file, the bash command need to copy this block of code, and replace the CITY-FROM-TEXT-FILE-LINE-1 attribute from city.txt (one city per line)

```
<ss:Row ss:Height ="22">
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">CITY-FROM-TEXT-FILE-LINE-1</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">CALIFORNIA</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">CA</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
        </ss:Row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file `template.xml` containing the text above

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") ; for C in `cat city.txt` ; do sed s/CITY-FROM-TEXT-FILE-LINE-1/$C/ template.xml ; done > cities.xml
```

Commands used

- `cat` ; concatenate a file to STDOUT
- `sed` ; stream editor

We also use the standard bash for loop mechanism, and redirection to a file.

For further reading I recommend ;

- [Advanced bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) (also good for beginners)
- [Sculpting text with grep, sed and awk](http://matt.might.net/articles/sculpting-text/) (an introduction to three of the most useful text-processing tools on Unix)

Comment: This is great, how ever some of the cities names are two words and now the output breaks the names.

Comment: You always learn something posting here ; the IFS variable controls how bash splits loop input (apparently). Have edited one-liner to reflect this - it splits on NEWLINE or BACKSPACE (not sure why the backspace, but hey...)

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough information to know exactly what you're desiring, but I'll try to take a guess, and it may help.  If you had a file called `cities.txt` which contained:

```
xx
CITY-FROM-TEXT-FILE-LINE-1
CALIFORNIA
CA
xx
```

and then you ran the `awk` command on that input:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "<ss:Row ss:Height =\"22\">"}{printf "  <ss:Cell>\n    <ss:Data ss:Type=\"String\">%s</ss:Data>\n  </ss:Cell>\n",$0}END{print "</ss:Row>"}' < cities.txt
```

then you would should the output:

```
<ss:Row ss:Height ="22">
  <ss:Cell>
    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
  </ss:Cell>
  <ss:Cell>
    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">CITY-FROM-TEXT-FILE-LINE-1</ss:Data>
  </ss:Cell>
  <ss:Cell>
    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">CALIFORNIA</ss:Data>
  </ss:Cell>
  <ss:Cell>
    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">CA</ss:Data>
  </ss:Cell>
  <ss:Cell>
    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
  </ss:Cell>
</ss:Row>
```

This may not answer your query directly, but hopefully should get you one possible way (of many) to get your started.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is infect the result I am trying to get, I do have a city.txt file which have a city name per line, and all this is static it stays the same but the:
CITY-FROM-TEXT-FILE-LINE-1

xx
 
CALIFORNIA
CA
xx

Comment: @eddie: If you paste a snippet of your actual `city.txt` I can try and tweak the command above (or you can tweak it *yourself!* ). Without knowing what you're actually dealing with, I can only really guess.

Comment: The city.txt have only city names in this format:
city1
city2
etc

Comment: @eddie: does the `city.txt` file contain each of the names "*city1*, *city2*, etc" all on one line (separated by eg. spaces/commas); or one *city* per line; or one *city* and several other pieces of data per line; or something else?  I'm happy to assist further, but it would be very useful if you could paste a short snippet to clarify what the input looks like.

Comment: im sorry im not clear to begin with .. 

It is one city name per line no commas or anything like that

Thanks